# Measuring efficiency of Mutex and Busy waiting

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

The program is to create several threads where each thread increments a shared variable by 10000 using a for loop that increments it by 1 in every iteration. Both mutex lock and spin lock (busy waiting) versions are required. According to what I've learned, mutex version should work faster than spin lock. But what I implemented gave me an opposite answer...

This is the inplementation of each thread in the mutex version:

```
void *incr(void *tid)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);     //Grab the lock
        sharedVar++;    //Increment the shared variable
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);   //Release the lock
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

And this is the implementation in the spin lock version:

```
void *incr(void *tid)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        enter_region((int)tid);  //Grab the lock
        sharedVar++;        //Increment the shared variable
        leave_region((int)tid);  //Release the lock
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
void enter_region(int tid)
{
    interested[tid] = true;     //Show this thread is interested
    turn = tid;     //Set flag
    while(turn == tid && other_interested(tid));    //Busy waiting
}
bool other_interested(int tid)    //interested[] is initialized to all false
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < tNumber; i++)
        if(i != tid)
            if(interested[i] == true)   //There are other threads that are interested
                return true;
    return false;
}
void leave_region(int tid)
{
    interested[tid] = false;    //Depart from critical region
}
```

I also iterated the process of threads creating and running for hundreds of times to make sure the execution time can be distinguished. 
For example, if tNumber is 4, and I iterated the program for 1000 times, mutex will take me 2.22 sec, and spin lock will take me 1.35 sec. The difference grows as tNumber increases. Why is this happening? Is my code wrong?

Comment: Your 'spin lock' doesn't lock anything.  It can never work correctly on a multi-core cpu.  Sure, borken code can be faster.  Make your loop much longer to ensure concurrency and a bad value for the shared variable.

Comment: @HansPassant Correct.  I would add that a correct implementation of a spinlock almost always uses some kind of test & set or load-link/store-conditional construct, and those tend to be hardware-specific.

Comment: This code is almost exact to the one in College tests. At least at ours.

Comment: @UmNyobe - I would double check the text - they would need a mutex supplied by the OS to get it to work correctly.

Comment: That's not a spinlock. That's some strange variation of Dekker's synchronization.

Comment: I don't know how I can make it into a real spin-lock one...The code in the textbook looks the same, and I still can't derive a solution from your words...

Comment: @ninjalj. Thanks!! that is what I was talking about. Only work for 2 threads

Comment: @ninjalj I'm actually implementing Peterson's solution on my book...Do you mean it only works for 2 threads?

Comment: @goldfrapp04: No. I mean _spinlock ≠ Dekker's synchronization_. Use pthread's spinlocks if your system supports them. Besides, Dekker's synchronization also needs proper visibility and ordering (usually via using inline asm or compiler intrinsics).

Comment: Just by coincidence :) there was a very similar question today. Is this your class mate? [Wrong implementation of Peterson's algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443392/wrong-implementation-of-petersons-algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code between `enter_region` and `leave_region` is not protected.

You can prove this by making it more complicated to ensure that it will trip itself up.

Create an array of bools (check) of length 10000 set up false. Make the code between enter and leave:

```
if (check[sharedVar]) cout << "ERROR" << endl;
else check[sharedVar++] = true;
```

Comment: I modified my code as you said, but running it returned Segmentation Fault...If I modified those 2 lines back to sharedVal++; then it works normally.

Comment: Oops - the array should be of size tNumber * 1000 then add a little more just in case. Sorry. Either way, as others have pointed out, your spin lock does not lock.

Comment: Thanks. I rewrote the 2 lines as "if(!check[sharedVar]) check[sharedVar++] = true;" and the execution time is still less than that of mutex. Is your code simply for the purpose of making it loop longer or doing some protection? I still can't get that...

Comment: Yeah it did...but it printed out so many that the execution time for tNumber = 2 increased to 51.48 sec while the initial wrong version only takes 1.XX sec...How should I implement the spin lock itself?

Comment: It prints out the error message when two threads share the same value for sharedVar - which should not be possible. You could even just change the code to `cout << sharedVar++<<endl` and the list of numbers should be monotonic. If not your code is not locking anything.

Comment: Last comment - There is no point in implementing a spin lock - most OS provide a mutex

Comment: _spinlock ≠ mutex_ Pthread has an optional extension for spinlocks, though I wouldn't use spinlocks from userspace (you never know when you will be preemptied, and for how long).

Comment: I know but they achieve the same thing. Also it is impossible to implement in a high level language.

Comment: I take the last comment back about being impossible to implement - forgot abot Pettersons algorithm. My memory.

Comment: Peterson's algorithm still needs appropriate compiler and CPU barriers.

Comment: @ninjalj - This is really testing my memory - learnt about this stuff over 20 years ago and have not used it since.

Comment: Thanks to all! I think pthread_spin_lock and the relevant are what I'm looking for and probably what our homework requires for "implementing spin lock"...I tried and still got the result that spinlock worked faster than mutex. Is this the truth? Also, I read another interesting discussion here: http://www.alexonlinux.com/pthread-mutex-vs-pthread-spinlock. Somebody said that spinlock is possibly faster but consumes more CPU...How can this be explained more clearly?

Comment: spin lock is like your boss saying to you get ready but twiddle your thumbs, while he hangs about ready to tell you to start. When the work is avaiable he can shout at you straight away. Mutex - the boss goes away, does something else and then notices the he can get you to do something. He then wanders back via the coffee machine and then tells you to get on with it.

Comment: Well, after more research I found that spinlock is faster when the critical region runs very fast. Mutex performs more slowly in this case because it uses system calls. But in cases where execution time is mostly bounded by the critical region itself and where competition to obtain the lock is very intense, mutex will work faster.

Comment: You also should note the effect of have the processor not doing useful work on others using that processor.

Answer (score 0):

The "difference" in speed is that you are implementing synchronization using

```
interested[tid] = true;     //Show this thread is interested
turn = tid;     //Set flag
while(turn == tid && other_interested(tid));
```

which are sequential operations. Any thread can be preempted while he is doing that, and the next thread read an erroneous state.

It need to be done atomically, by implementing either a `compare-and-swap` or a `test-and-set`. These instructions are usually provided by the hardware.

For eg on x86 you have `xchg, cmpxchg/cmpxchg8b, xadd`
Your test could be rewritten as

```
while( compare_and_swap_atomic(myid,id_meaning_it_is_free) == false);
```

The issue is that  ***atomicity is expensive*** .

Comment: Just to add on that, in C11 you have `atomic_flag` that is the perfect primitive data type for a spinlock.