# Do we need an mfence in the unlock() function of Peterson's lock on x86?

Tags: c++, c, locking

Peterson's lock code taken from [(german) wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmus_von_Peterson):

```
# define FALSE 0
# define TRUE 1
# define N 2 

int turn; 
int interested[N]; 

void enter_region(int process)
{
  int other; 
  other = 1 - process; 
  interested[process] = TRUE; 
  turn = other;

  while (interested[other] == TRUE && turn == other) ; 
}

void leave_region(int process)  
{
  interested[process] = FALSE;  
}
```

Can somebody think of an example where a bug is happening without an mfence in the `leave_region` function?

N.B.: I know for sure that a mfence is required in the `enter_region` function.

Comment: @WeatherVane "critical region".  We're talking about synchronization primitives.

Comment: I understand the algorithm as descriptive, i.e. closer to pseudo code than real code for a real platform. I don't think the implementation is meant to be written and built with your preferred compiler of choice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks, I can see this is a semaphore system, but didn't grasp the abbreviation. I have used threads that communicate status or instruction by r/w (but not read-modify-write) memory locations. Re your answer, could this also be achieved by a read after the write to the shared data memory, before calling `leave_region()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane, no, no amount of reading and writing inside the critical region (therefore by one thread running on a specific core) reliably prevents apparent reordering of that thread's reads and writes with respect to those of a thread running on a different core.  You need a memory barrier for that, such as the `mfence` instruction provides.  On the other hand, store / load reordering is not an issue in any case for the thread that executed the code in the CR -- a single core will never confuse *itself* about access order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  It doesn't require any particularly unusual situation.

Suppose that a computation is performed in the CR, with the final action being to store the result to memory.  Suppose further that soon after the CR, another thread reads the target memory with the purpose of obtaining the computation result.  The read must not be reordered with the write else the wrong value will be obtained.  To avoid that, an `mfence` (or other instruction that serves as a memory barrier) is required when you leave the CR.

Comment: I think I got it. So even if in the source code the second thread is started after the first thread left the CR (in the source code) there is a possibility that the read of the second thread happens before the write of the first thread - correct?

Comment: In any thread implementation worth using, a new thread's view of memory is initially consistent with its parent thread's.  Thus, if it is the thread that ran in the CR that starts the new thread, then the new thread should see all writes performed in the CR by its parent.  That does not automatically apply, however, if it is different thread that starts the new one.  As a practical matter, it is implementation-dependent what effect starting a new thread may have with respect to thread pairs other than the (parent, child) pair.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think an mfence is needed in unlock(). Rationale: Peterson's unlock just needs to be a store-release for all I know. In x86 non-temporal (and non write-combining) stores seem to have release semantics. See also: https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/intel-memory-ordering-and-c++-memory-model.html

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. There is a paper that explains why we need the second mfence on x86: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~naliniv/papers/2010-pact-locks.pdf In short: You need it for linearizability. Actually I'm not sure anymore that this answer is really addressing this issue or something else.

Comment: @ben, How is "you need it for linearizability" semantically different from what I said?  As applied to your question, it would seem that the desired linearizability / atomicity is for the work performed in the critical region.  Ensuring that the operations performed in the CR, including the last one, are not reordered with respect to those of another thread, at least from those two threads' points of view, is practically a definition of linearizability.  You asked for an example, and I gave you a whole class of them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to apologize for any misunderstanding. The reason for why I mentioned this in the comment is since my understanding in this matter deepened since I accepted the answer. "Ensuring that the operations performed in the CR, including the last one, are not reordered with respect to those of another thread" I'm not sure whether I understand this part correctly. After all, re-ordering is something that happens locally on a core (yet it might still have inter-core consequences). Maybe you can make an example?

Comment: @ben, your question is about C-level semantics, which don't have machine-instruction granularity.  My answer is about the order of reads and writes to memory, with respect to C semantics, as perceived by each thread.  In part because of machine instruction reordering, but largely because of register and cache usage, different threads can see reads and writes in different orders.  Not much else actually matters as far as the need for thread synchronization goes, and that's what `mfence`, locking, linearizability, and my answer are all about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger My point is that the second mfence does not have to do anything with orders. It is required on x86 to make the changes in the CR globally visible. See the paper I mentioned for details.

Comment: @ben, why do you think that has nothing to do with order?  If, from its own point of view, thread T1 updates a modifiable lvalue, then at any given point in its execution, any other thread T2 has either seen that write or it has not.  That is inherently a question of the order memory writes performed by T1 relative to the order of reads performed by T2, as viewed by T2.  Without a memory barrier, T1's writes can be reordered into the indefinite future from T2's view.  With a memory barrier, that does not happen, therefore the write is visible to T2 at a predictable point in its execution.

Comment: @ben, to put it more simply, saying that a given write is visible to a given read is the same thing as saying that the write is ordered before the read (and no other write to the same location happens between).  The complication here is that when the write and read are performed by separate threads, the threads may have different views of the order of those operations.  That's what a memory barrier prevents.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think we are talking of the same thing. I'm saying the fence flushes the store buffer to make writes of the CR globally visible. And that same store buffer is the reason for why the memory model of x86 is not sequentially consistent and reorderings can happen. Imagine the thread that wrote something in the CR goes to sleep immediately after leaving the CR with all the writes still sleeping in its store buffer. Then those writes are not reordered with anything as there is nothing coming after the CR, still they are not visible to another threa.