# How to make a code for critical section in c for n processes(Bakery algorithm)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, algorithm, pthreads

I have got a project from my university for critical section problem of n processes. I have made a code for 2 processes in c But I could not figure out how to get it working for n process . The code is in C for linux threads.

Here is code for 2 Processes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int flag[2];
int turn;
const int MAX = 1e9;
int ans = 0;


void lock_init(){
    flag[0]=flag[1]=0;
    turn = 0;
}

void lock(int self){
    flag[self]=1;
    turn = 1-self;

    while(flag[1-self]==1 && turn == 1-self);
}

void unlock(int self){
    flag[self]=0;
}

void* func(void *s){
    int i=0;
    int *limitptr = (int*) s;
    int self = *limitptr;
    printf("Thread %d in queue for critical section\n",self);

    lock(self);

    printf("Thread %d in critical section\n",self);
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){

        ans++;

    }
     printf("Thread %d done counting\n",self);
    printf("Thread %d is exiting critical section\n",self);
    unlock(self);
}

int main(){

    pthread_t p1, p2;
    int a=0,b=1;
    lock_init();

    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, func, &a);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, func, &b);

    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);

    printf("Exiting Main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You. :)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm

Comment: or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588514/a-tested-implementation-of-peterson-lock-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

use a `mutex`

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

declare the mutex like so:

```
pthread_mutex_t myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

then at the beginning of a critical section call:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &myMutex );
```

and at the end of the critical section call:

```
pthread_mutex_unlock( &myMutex );
```

it does not matter how many threads are using that critical section, only one thread will be able to access it at a time

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your valuable time and answers.
I Found A solution for My problem and thought of sharing it.I Implemented Bakery Algorithm In C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

int N;
int global = 10;
int entering[100];
int number[100];

int max(int number[100]) {
    int i = 0;
    int maximum = number[0];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (maximum < number[i])
            maximum = number[i];
        }
    return maximum;
    }

void lock(int i) {
    int j = 0;
    entering[i] = TRUE;
    number[i] = 1 + max(number);
    entering[i] = FALSE;
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        while (entering[j]);
        while (number[j] != 0 && (number[j] < number[i] || (number[i] == number[j]) && j < i)) {}
    }
}

void unlock(int i) {
    number[i] = 0;
}

void *fn(void *integer) {
    int i = (int) integer;
    lock(i);
    printf("\n\n-----------Process %d---------",i);
    printf("\nProcess %d is Entering Critical Section\n",i);
    global++;
    printf("%d is the value of global \n",global);
    printf("Process %d is leaving Critical Section\n",i);
    printf("----------------------------------\n\n");
    unlock(i);
}    


int main()
{
    printf("Enter Number of Process\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int th[N];
    void *fn(void *);
    pthread_t thread[N];
    int i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        th[i] = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, fn, (void *)i); 
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Again Thank You :)

Comment: this answer will only have a single thread running at any one point in time.  Therefore there  is no need for a 'critical' section.  Therefore this is not a good answer. as it does not exhibit a good critical section example.